# send mail if there is at least one valid recipient

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have some code that sends emails using `javax.mail.Transport` class.
The code calls the send method, but if there is any invalid address the message won't be send.

Is there any way to send the message to valid addresses and ignore invalid ones?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid addresses? Addressed that don't exist? Addresses that aren't formatted properly?

Comment: addresses that don't exist-specifically their domain doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be solved easily by putting a property in the properties like this

```
props.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");
```

This will tell java to send mail even if there are not valid reciepients

Answer (score 1):

> addresses that don't exist-specifically their domain doesn't exist

You could perform a [java DNS lookup](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/58/using-java-to-get-detailed-dns-information/). That can help verify if the domain exists. But there is no way to know if a given address is valid or not, even if the server exists. If there were a way to do this, spam bots would have a field day :). A verified email address is a valuable asset to certain individuals.

Comment: Actually there is a semi-correct way, some servers pretend to send a mail to the emailaddress and stop after they send the recipient data, because many mailservers will stop the conversation as soon as they receive an unknown recipient. This is usually done to verify the send of the mail. But when you pretend to send the mail, then you might send it directly ;-) And the drawback is due to spambot protection some mailservers accept any mail and discard it afterwards.